# AMQP + NodeJS wait for channel

Tags: node.js, async-await, amqp, channel, feathersjs

I have a service in FeathersJS that initiates a connection to RabbitMQ, the issue is how to await for a channel to be ready before receiving requests:

```
class Service {
  constructor({ amqpConnection, queueName }) {
    this.amqpConnection = amqpConnection;
    this.queueName = queueName;
    this.replyQueueName = queueName + "Reply"
  }

  async create(data, params) {
    new Promise(resolve => {
      if (!this.channel) await this.createChannel();
      channel.responseEmitter.once(correlationId, resolve);
      channel.sendToQueue(this.queueName, Buffer.from(data), {
        correlationId: asyncLocalStorage.getStore(),
        replyTo: this.replyQueueName,
      });
    });
  }

  async createChannel() {
    let connection = this.amqpConnection();
    let channel = await connection.createChannel();

    await channel.assertQueue(this.queueName, {
      durable: false,
    });

    this.channel = channel;
    channel.responseEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    channel.responseEmitter.setMaxListeners(0);
    channel.consume(
      this.replyQueueName,
      (msg) => {
        channel.responseEmitter.emit(
          msg.properties.correlationId,
          msg.content.toString("utf8")
        );
      },
      { noAck: true }
    );
  }
  ....
}
```

Waiting for the channel to be created during a request seems like a waste. How should this be done "correctly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feathers services can implement a [setup method](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#setup-app-path) which will be called when the server is started (or you call `app.setup()` yourself):

```
class Service {
  async setup () {
    await this.createChannel();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there an async `setup` option at a higher level - as in, create the connection at app level and then the channel at service level?